# i want to update from .net framework 4.0 to 4.5 or older (winetricks)

Tags: wine, winetricks, dotnet

maybe this is so dumb lol but yeah I didn't know I needed `dotnet45`, I try to install it and it starts the net framework setup and shows me if I want to repair or uninstall the .net framework if I click uninstall that won't work. if I click repair, it repairs it but keeps the same version. idk what to do.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Sorry I do not see how this has to do with Ubuntu it has to do with a Windows product or maybe Wine.

Answer (score 0):

To install .NET do the following:

- for custom named WINEPREFIX:

  1. start `winetricks` application
  2. select needed prefix in wizard, click OK
  3. select Install a Windows DLL or component, click OK
  4. check *dotnet45* and/or *dotnet452*, click OK
  5. wait wizard to finish
- for default WINEPREFIX

  ```
  winetricks dotnet45 # dotnet452
  ```