# How to Install ExpressSCH Plus Schematic and ExpressPCB Plus Layout that Use .Net 4.5 on the Latest Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with the Latest Repository Wine

Tags: wine, windows-10, winetricks

I am trying to get the latest versions of ExpressSCH Plus Schematic and also ExpressPlus PCB Layout software version 3.2.0 0 on Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS.  However when I launch the applications from the desktop with the right mouse button to select Wine as the launch application I get a number of error messages, some of which mention that .Net 4.5 is not installed properly.

Older versions of ExpressPCB would work fine in Ubuntu Wine with minor issues.  But these versions I cannot find any longer to test.

I am looking for simple instructions to get this ExpressPCB Plus software to install and properly launch in a x64 environment (with also x32 support downloaded into the latest Wine installation 8.0.02.

Thank you for any insight, suggestions, and help.

Some related links might be:

[Install .NET](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327452/i-want-to-update-from-net-framework-4-0-to-4-5-or-older-winetricks)

[Help Installing .NET](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=34691)

[What is Wine](https://www.winehq.org/)

[Wine .Net 45 Hangs](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49897)

Update:  I found the classic ExpressPCB and ExpressSCH program links at [Express PCB Download Classic](https://www.expresspcb.com/previous-versions/) and was able to eventually get both of these to launch successfully.  Also LTSpice launches fairly well.

Also [.Net Framework 3.5 Wine Database](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=13088) seems to have interesting suggestions.  However, I end up getting this error message that I have not gotten around for ExpressSCH Plus to run.

[image: Error Message when attempting instructions for .Net Framework 3.6 Database]

When I try to download the .Net 3.5 Service Pack 1 from the Microsoft Site, the download does not start and eventually times out.  Hopefully, I can get both pieces of software (the classic and current ExpressPCBPlus and ExpressPCB Classic to run).  I am still not sure what to do though and appreciate further suggestions and help about the ExpressPCBPlus Schematic and Layout versions.